# Laravel array of objects validation

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I'm trying to do a validation in Laravel for an associative array of objects.

A valid JSON string that I pass to the controller looks like this:

```
{
    'create': [
        {
            'artnr': '123456',
            'unit':  'Stk.'
        },
        {
            'artnr': '23456',
            'unit':  'Kg.'
        }
    ],
    'update': [
        {
            'id': 1
            'artnr': '567890',
            'unit':  'Stk.'
        },
        {
            'id': 2
            'artnr': '67836',
            'unit':  'Kg.'
        }
    ]
}
```

The controller function which validates the data looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->replace(array(
        'create' => json_decode($request->create),
        'update' => json_decode($request->update)
    ));

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'create' => 'required|array',
        'create.*.artnr' => 'required|max:20',
        'create.*.unit' => 'max:20',
        'update' => 'required|array',
        'update.*.id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
        'update.*.artnr' => 'required|max:20',
        'update.*.unit' => 'max:20'
    ])->validate();
}
```

Although I specify in the `store` function that an `artnr` must exist for every object, the controller doesn't throw an error when I pass an object without an `artnr`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

Okay so after following user2486's suggestion and using different sample data, I now found out that the validator works when I pass the properties like `id`, `artnr`, `unit` as an **associative array**. Like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'create' => array(
        array(
            'artnr' => '123456',
            'unit' => 'Kg'
        ), array(
            'unit' => 'Stk.'
        )
    ), 'update' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'unit' => 'Stk.'
        ), array(
            'id' => 2,
            'artnr' => '123456',
            'unit' => 'Kg'
        )
    )
);
```

When I decode my JSON string however, the properties are parsed into an **object** and therefore no errors are thrown!

Is it possible that the validator rules use a different kind of notation for objects?

If it should not be possible to validate objects, I think I would just convert every object into an associative array.

Comment: Can you include sample data you send that you think are invalid?

Comment: Did check that you have valid json ?

Comment: Just test with sample array instead getting json and convert to array , I am sure it will work , you need check you conversion code

Comment: What you get in `return dd($request->all() );` ?

Comment: @user2486 Thanks for your help! I did a few tests and updated my question.

Comment: you can check for `$request->create` like if `object` or `array` and convert accordingly and check what value or output you get after converting ?

Comment: I've found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the solution was to call my `json_decode` functions like this
`json_decode($request->create, true)`.
With the second parameter set to `true` the function converts every JSON object into an associative array.